# Get value of column searching in between dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to get the field "Name" from "Table1" in a calculated column in "Table2", like:

Table1:

```
Name | Date
ABC  | 5-jan-2017
ABC  | 7-jan-2017
DEF  | 8-may-2018
DEF  | 10-jun-2018
```

And Table2:

```
Date         | CalcColumn
6-Jan-2017   | ABC
25-may-2018  | DEF
```

The logic is the following:
If `Date` in `Table2` is within the minimum and maximum dates of `Table1` then get the name in `Table1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend reshaping `Table1` so that each `Name` has two columns, `StartDate` and `EndDate` instead of having those in separate rows. If you don't, you can create that table as a variable as follows:

```
CalcColumn =
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1,
        Table1[Name],
        "StartDate", MIN ( Table1[Date] ),
        "EndDate", MAX ( Table1[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            Summary,
            Table2[Date] >= [StartDate] &&
            Table2[Date] <= [EndDate] ),
        Table1[Name]
    )
```

You only need the part after the `RETURN` if your data is reshaped.

Comment: you got it again! I was very, very close this time but couldn't make it. Thank you!